# Differentiable Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $c\in[a,b]$. Then show that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$, $x_n\neq c$, such that 
$$f'(c) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f'(x_n).$$

I am lost in knowing how to use this and where to go from here.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: The "So far I have..." is not actually true; the mean value theorem tells you that there is SOME $c\in(a,b)$ which satisfies this property.  There's no reason to suspect this is true for the $c$ that you've chosen!  Otherwise, every function has a constant derivative.

Comment: so then where do I begin with this problem?

Comment: @user72195 I've given you detailed hints which almost resemble a complete solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume that $c\in (a,b)$; I'll leave you to consider the cases $c=a$ and $c=b$ which are identical in nature to the one that I'm going to consider. Choose $x_1\in (c,b)$ such that:

**(1)** $f'(x_1)=\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}$

using the mean value theorem applied to $f$ on the interval $[c,b]$. (Check that you understand this!) Now repeat: choose $x_2\in (c,x_1)$ such that:

**(2)** $f'(x_2)=\frac{f(x_1)-f(c)}{x_1-c}$

using the mean value theorem applied to $f$ on the interval $[c,x_1]$. Again: choose $x_3\in (c,x_2)$ such that:

**(3)** $f'(x_3)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(c)}{x_2-c}$

using the mean value theorem applied to $f$ on the interval $[c,x_2]$. Continue this process inductively to obtain a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

We've obtained a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $c<\cdots<x_{n+1}<x_n<x_{n-1}<\cdots<x_2<x_1$ and:

**(n)** $f'(x_n)=\frac{f(x_{n-1})-f(c)}{x_{n-1}-c}$.

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges and that $f'(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f'(x_n)$. (*Hint*: Use **(1)**, **(2)**, ..., **(n)**, ... above. You can assume $\{x_n\}$ converges if you can't prove this and solve the second part of this ***Exercise***. Also, you need to use the differentiability of $f$ at $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ here!)

Now here's the subtlety: we don't actually know that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=c$. For example, it could just so have turned out that $c=\frac{1}{2}\in [0,1]$ and $x_n=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{n+4}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Of course, in this case, $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \frac{3}{4}\neq c=\frac{1}{2}$. So:

***Exercise 2***: How can we modify the construction of the $x_n$'s to ensure that also $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = c$. Once we have this, ***Exercise 1*** completes the proof! (*Hint*: In the construction of $x_n$ we applied the mean value theorem of $f$ to the interval $[c,x_{n-1}]$. Why not apply the mean value theorem to a smaller closed interval with $c$ still as the left endpoint to ensure that the $x_n$'s get closer and closer to $c$?)

I hope this helps! Notice I haven't given a complete answer if you don't do the ***Exercises***. If you do ***Exercise 2***, then you'll have a complete answer in addition to a solution of ***Exercise 1***. Let me know if you have any difficulties with the two ***Exercises*** and I'm happy to help!

Comment: would the smaller interval be [c,x_n-c]? I'm kind of following what you are asking but I'm still slightly confused on how to show that the limit of Xn = c.

Comment: @user72195 I don't think so for two reasons: (a) If you're considering an interval $[a,b]$, then you probably want $a<b$ and there's no guarantee that $c<x_n-c$ and (b) even if you did know $[c,x_n-c]$ is a well-defined interval, i.e., $c<x_n-c$, then this is equivalent to $2c<x_n$ which surely can't imply $x_n\to c$ in general. So, what you need is an interval $[c,y]$ such that (i) $c<y$ and (ii) $c$ and $y$ are "sufficiently close". What does this mean? If $x_{n}\in [c,x_{n-1}]$ as constructed above, then we don't know that $x_{n-1}$ is close to $c$ ...

Comment: @user72195 ... Why not take a number closer to $c$ than $x_{n-1}$ as the right endpoint of the interval? Can you give an example of such a number?

Comment: do you mean something like c+1?

Comment: @user72195 It's not exactly what I had in mind. Choosing $c+1$ would ensure that $\left|x_n-c\right|<1$ for all $n$ but that still doesn't guarantee that $x_n\to c$. The right endpoint of the interval should be variable depending on $n$ and should get closer and closer to $c$ as $n$ increases ...

Comment: I still just do not seem to be understanding what I am to do here.

Comment: @user72195 OK, choose the right endpoint of the interval to be $c+\frac{1}{n}$. That is, choose the interval to be $[c,c+\frac{1}{n}]$. In the inductive construction of $x_n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, choose $x_n\in (c,c+\frac{1}{n})$ such that $f'(x_n)=\frac{f(c+\frac{1}{n})-f(c)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ by applying the  mean value theorem to $f$ on $[c,c+\frac{1}{n}]$. Now, we do have $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=c$ as well as the other conditions being satisfied! What do you think now?

Comment: how does what f'(xn) equal imply that the limit of xn = c?

Comment: @user72195 $x_n\in (c,c+\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular, $\left|x_n-c\right|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=c$.

Comment: @user72195 What do you think of the problem now? Do you think you understand the solution?